# Expo SQLite rendering infinite number of component

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo

I'm currently writing a react native app using expo and its sqlite database.
I fetch some data from my database then rendering a number of component, one for each row of my select query.

The problem i have is that instead of rendering the right numner of component with the right data, it's rendering an infinite number of component with no data.

the code (the weird rendering happens in the elem.map) :

```js
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Picker, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View} from "react-native";
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";
import {useFocusEffect} from "@react-navigation/native";
import Arbre from "../Localisation/Arbre";
import Styles from "../Styles";
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('Agora');

const addDesignation = (n, s, c, sc, d) => {
    console.log(n+'\n'+s+'\n'+c+'\n'+sc+'\n'+d);
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        let idp;
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM CURRENTID ", [], (tx, rs) => {
            idp=rs.rows.item(0).currentCompId;
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO ELEMENT (nom, strate, classe, sousClasse, denom, idComp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", [n, s, c, sc, d, idp],
                (tx, rs) => {}, (tx, e) => console.log(e));
        })
    })
}


const Designation = ({navigation}) => {
    const [elem, setElem] = useState([]);
    const [nom, setNom] = useState();
    const [strate, setStrate] = useState();
    const [classe, setClasse] = useState();
    const [sc, setSc] = useState();
    const [denom, setDenom] = useState();

    const selectElem = (comp) => {
        db.transaction( (tx) => {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM ELEMENT WHERE idCOmp = ?", [comp], (tx, rs) => {
                let res = [];
                for (let i = 0; i<rs.rows.length; i++) {
                    console.log(rs.rows.item(i).nom);
                    res.push(rs.rows.item(i));
                }
                setElem(res);
            })
        });
    };

    useFocusEffect(() => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            let idp;
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM CURRENTID ", [], (tx, rs) => {
                idp=rs.rows.item(0).currentCompId;
                selectElem(idp);
            })
        })

    });

    return (
        <>
            <View style={{flexDirection: "row", flex:1, width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
                <Arbre/>
                <View style={{flex: 2}}>
                    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'gray', flex:2, flexDirection: "column"}}>
                        {
                            elem.map(value => {
                                console.log('taille : '+elem.length);
                                return(
                                    <View key={value.idElem} style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
                                        <TextInput
                                            style={Styles.designPicker}
                                            onChangeText={(n) => {}}
                                            value={value.nom}
                                            placeholder="Nom de l'élément"
                                        />
                                        <Picker
                                            style={Styles.designPicker}
                                            selectedValue={value.strate}
                                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>{}}
                                        >
                                            <Picker.Item label='test' value='test'/>
                                        </Picker>
                                        <Picker
                                            style={Styles.designPicker}
                                            selectedValue={value.classe}
                                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {}}
                                        >
                                            <Picker.Item label='test' value='test'/>
                                        </Picker>
                                        <Picker
                                            style={Styles.designPicker}
                                            selectedValue={value.sousClasse}
                                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {}}
                                        >
                                            <Picker.Item label='test' value='test'/>
                                        </Picker>
                                        <Picker
                                            style={Styles.designPicker}
                                            selectedValue={value.denom}
                                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {}}
                                        >
                                            <Picker.Item label='test' value='test'/>
                                        </Picker>
                                        <TouchableOpacity
                                            onPress={addDesignation}
                                        >
                                            <AntDesign name="pluscircle" size={24} color="black"/>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                );
                            })
                        }

                        <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
                            <TextInput
                                style={Styles.designPicker}
                                onChangeText={(n) => {setNom(n)}}
                                value={nom}
                                placeholder="Nom de l'élément"
                            />
                            <Picker
                                style={Styles.designPicker}
                                selectedValue={strate}
                                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>{setStrate(itemValue)}}
                            >
                                <Picker.Item label='test' value='test'/>
                            </Picker>
                            <Picker
                                style={Styles.designPicker}
                                selectedValue={classe}
                                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {setClasse(classe)}}
                            >
                                <Picker.Item label='test' value='test'/>
                            </Picker>
                            <Picker
                                style={Styles.designPicker}
                                selectedValue={sc}
                                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {setSc(itemValue)}}
                            >
                                <Picker.Item label='test' value='test'/>
                            </Picker>
                            <Picker
                                style={Styles.designPicker}
                                selectedValue={denom}
                                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {setDenom(itemValue)}}
                            >
                                <Picker.Item label='test' value='test'/>
                            </Picker>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={addDesignation(nom, strate, classe, sc, denom)}
                            >
                                <AntDesign name="pluscircle" size={24} color="black"/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>

                    </View>
                </View>

            </View>
        </>
    );
}

export default Designation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty dependency array, that should fixe the loop.

```
 useFocusEffect(() => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            let idp;
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM CURRENTID ", [], (tx, rs) => {
                idp=rs.rows.item(0).currentCompId;
                selectElem(idp);
            })
        })

    }, []);
```

Comment: with useFocusEffect, i need to use useCallback and then have the dependency array at the end of the useCallback, but when i do that i get the "invalid hook call"

Answer (score 0):

the problem i had was that i wrote addDesignation instead of () => addDesignation on the touchableopacity, leading the method to add every second